# generic array creation and type parameters confusion

Tags: java, arrays, generics

```
public interface Pair<K, V>{
  K getKey();
  V getValue();
}

public class OrderedPair<K, V> implements Pair<K, V>{
  private K key;
  private V value;

  OrderedPair(K k, V v){
    key = k;
    value = v;
  }

  public K getKey(){
    return key;
  }

  public V getValue(){
    return value;
  }
}

public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    OrderedPair<Integer, String> myPair = new OrderedPair<>(100, "Imam Bux");
    OrderedPair<Integer, String> myPair2 = new OrderedPair<>(101, "Pakistan");

    OrderedPair<Integer, String>[] myArray = { myPair, myPair2 };
  }
}
```

Question: I have created an interface Pair which is implemented by OrderedPair which is instantiated twice by Main class. key and value of OrderedPair refers to which on of it's above type parameter?

Problem: I want to create OrderedPair array but end up with the "generic array creation" error. If I can make String[] names = { "ABC", "DEF" }; then why not `OrderedPair[]` array?

Answer (score 0):

The creators of Java don't want you to have arrays of generic types.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays

So, instead of using arrays, you should turn to Java collections; for example you could be using an ArrayList>.

This is caused by the fact on how generics are implemented in Java. When generics were added, the language designers decided to guarantee backwards compatibility on a source code level. This decision has several consequences:

- on the one hand, all existing Java source code that is using classes like ArrayList or Map ... still compiles (also producing compiler warnings)
- on the other hand, this specific implementation caused severe restrictions on generics; the fact that you can't create arrays with generic types is one of it (I recommend to study the Oracle tutorial on that topic; its really worth reading).

ArrayList or other Collection types were reworked in a way that is compatible with generics; and that was simply not possible with array types.

For your other question: there are no C++ like typedefs in java, so if you want to avoid typing OrderedPair all the time, you would have to create a specific subclass, like

```
class MyOrderedPair extends OrderedPair<String, Integer> ...
```

Comment: You mean that there is not way of making our own array? what happens in ArrayList that makes array like effect?

Comment: and kindly reply my question too if you find my question understandable?

Comment: Thanks for providing a nice answer.

Comment: But besides this I also asked a question about how a generic class implements a generic interface with same type parameters?